# PCA Score plot Matlab with confidence limits

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, pca, confidence-interval

I am trying to plot my Principle component plots with the confidence interval ovals I am not sure how to do this this is currently my plot code:

```
figure;
plot(score(:,1),score(:,2),'o');
xlabel('t1');ylabel('t2')
for i = 1:length (score)
    text(score(i,1),score(i,2), ['(' num2str(i), ')'])
end
```

Comment: I am trying to get the ellipse hotelling T2 onto the PCA which I did type into google and couldn't find anything.